# html table mixed up when echo from while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

HTML Table getting mixed up when having echo in while loop. Bellow attached the output image for that. How can i get normal table with loop result? Please note i am getting table data by searching with manual date.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_date'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['m_date'])) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: Select date then search</div>';
    }else{
        $m_date = $_POST['m_date'];
        $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bazar_dor WHERE m_date='$m_date'");
echo '<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <th>Category Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
';

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            echo '<td>'.$cat_name.'</td><td>'.$price.'</td>';
        }

echo '</tr></table>';

    }
}
?>
```

[the output i am getting from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4SAL.jpg)

Comment: Why you down vote my answer it is corrct just check it

Comment: I recommend showing a screenshot of the expected output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to include table rows (`<tr>`) inside your loop, as well. Your current code outputs all data on the same row, which undoubtedly breaks the table.

```
echo '<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Category Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>';

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
  $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
  $price = $row['price'];
  echo '<tr><td>'.$cat_name.'</td><td>'.$price.'</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your cede with this

```
    <?php if (isset($_POST['submit_date'])) { if    (empty($_POST['m_date'])) { echo '<div
        class="alert alert-danger">Error: Select date then search</div>'; }else{ $m_date = $_POST['m_date']; 
$q =    mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bazar_dor WHERE    m_date='$m_date'"); 
echo '<table style="width:100%"> <tr>
         <th>Category Name</th>   <th>Price</th>   </tr>  ';
while    ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { $cat_name = $row['cat_name']; 
$price    = $row['price']; echo '<tr><td>'.$cat_name.'</td><td>'.$price.'</td><\tr>'; 
} echo    '</table>'; 
} } ?>
```

Comment: Your answer contains a typo: `<\tr>` instead of `</tr>`. Also, it would be great to format your code and include an explanation of your solution.

Comment: I am online from mobile therefor the code format is incorrect but you get idea from it. So please accept it an up vote it.